# Beginner Question to $\epsilon-N$ Proofs

Tags: number-theory, limits, epsilon-delta

For particularly, $\epsilon-N$ proofs I was wondering why the following proposition holds true.

> Let $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$. Then, $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}}a+b\cdot f(n)=a+b\cdot \displaystyle{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}}f(n)$.

Comment: Small, but important nitpick: That is only true, if $\lim_{n→∞}f(n)$ exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $l = \lim\limits_{n\to +\infty} f(n)$.

For any $\epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}\text{ } / \text{ }n \geq N \Rightarrow |f(n)-l| \leq \epsilon$.

Then, for $ n \geq N$,

$$ |(a+b f(n))-(a+bl)| = |b|.|f(n)-l| \leq |b|\epsilon.$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It was done very well. I have been busy and haven't used the site for awhile. Your help is appreciated! Nice answer!

Comment: It is kind of a weird question because the limit is known prior. That's is neat how you did that.